# jquery Calendar action issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two calendar form

```
<label>Check In</label>
<input type="text" name="In" id="In" placeholder="Check-In" class="input-text full-width" />
<label>Check Out</label>
<input type="text" id="Out" name="Out" placeholder="Check-Out" class="input-text full-width" />
```

And js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Out").datepicker();
    $("#In").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(){
            var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $("#Out").datepicker("setDate", new Date(fecha.getTime()));
            $("#In").datepicker("setDate", "+15d");
        }
    });
});
```

What i need to acomplish : Date2 (Chec-Out) to be with 1 day after Date1 (Check-in)

I have tried the above code without success. COuld you please assist.

Comment: Do you mean that you want the "Out" date to be constrained to be within 1d plus or minus the "In" date, whatever it might be, at all time? If not, explain yourself better and add some numeric examples, please.

Comment: @A.Rama, The Out needs to be with >1 day that the In. Example if :In is 2015-01-20, the Out must be = or >  that 2015-01-21

Answer (score 0):

Try incrementing the in date so that the new date can be set in out calendar...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Out").datepicker();
$("#In").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
        var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+1);
        $("#Out").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
    }
    });
});
```

You use also try restricting the out calendar further by providing minDate...

[jQuery UI Datepicker minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#Out").datepicker();
$("#In").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(){
        var fecha = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        fecha.setDate(fecha.getDate()+1);
        $("#Out").datepicker("setDate", fecha);
        $("#Out").datepicker("option","minDate",fecha);
    }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the out date has to be AFTER the in date, you can set the minimum out date by doing something like this:

```
$("#Out").datepicker("option", "minDate", $("#In").datepicker("getDate"));
```